# Plot density of copula Clayton

Tags: r, copula

I want to plot the density and 2 variables of a Copula Clayton like the image following. I'm trying to plot this in R - is there a specific package I can use to get this image?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This question is best suited for Stackoverflow, I think.

Here is a possibility:

```
library(rgl)
library(copula)

Clayton <- claytonCopula(param = 0.5)

x <- y <- seq(0, 1, length = 30)
f <- function(x, y) { dCopula(cbind(x,y), Clayton) }
z <- outer(x, y, f)

persp3d(x, y, z, aspect = c(1, 1, 0.5), col = "lightblue",
        xlab = "u", ylab = "v", zlab = "density", polygon_offset = 1)
persp3d(x, y, z, front = "lines", back = "lines", 
        lit = FALSE, add = TRUE)
```

This graphic is interactive.

A non-interactive graphic, without the `rgl` package:

```
persp(Clayton, dCopula)
```

Comment: How can we do the same in Python?