# What is the meaning of maximum level in copula density plot?

Tags: correlation, joint-distribution, independence, copula

The copula density of 3 different pairs of variables is shown below. Why do the colorbar meters on the right-hand side of each plot have the same range, and what does the value $4.8$ mean exactly, compared to the value of dependence parameter $\theta \neq 4.8$? Are the colorbar ranges identical only because the variables have the same number of sample observations?

[image]
[image]
[image]

(This [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435599/plot-density-of-copula-clayton) shows a 3d rendition of what the Clayton copula looks like)

Comment: The white patches in the peak areas indicate regions where the density exceeds the maximum value shown on the scale.  That is, **your question is about a software artifact,** not about the copula itself.

Comment: thanks for describing the white patch, but what is the meaning of the 4.8 level? 4.8 of what? And why do all have this same roof. Any connection to $\theta$?

Comment: These are plots of the density (probability per unit area): that's part of the definition of a copula.  Typically the software selects the range of values to show based on an analysis of the values it is asked to show.  In your examples it has selected the same range for all three values of $\theta$ so we may conclude that for values *in this range* the software is likely to use the same limits.  I'm sure you can override those limits if you wish. Because the colorbar is determined by the density grid and not by the point scatterplot, it has nothing to do with sample size.

Comment: thanks, if 4.8 (or any level annointed manually rather than by the software) is some sort of proportionate sum, what is its relationship to the copula density also having a  proportionate sum, being 1? In other words, I knew about the summing to 1 of a density, and the dependence parameter, but textbooks seem to completely bypass the meaning or importance of the "4.8 height"

Comment: You would need to consult the software documentation.  I believe you have used a general-purpose plotting function, so it would be ignorant of the meaning of what you are plotting.